# Comments on Storedprocedures get truncate on mysqldump

Tags: mysql

How to include comments in stored procedures while taking mysql database back up. I am using mysql 5.5.16 server with following command:

`mysql -u root -p mydb<mydbbakup.sql`

I have also tried from sql yog with no success.

**UPDATE:**
The problem is with restore command. While opening the dump file with notepad all the comments in stored procedures are there. Any extra attributes needed for following restore command?

`mysql -u root -p mydb<mydbbakup.sql;`

Comment: With so little information it may be hard to give you a good answer. How was the backup file created? Have you checked that the comments are really stored in the backup file? Are there any errors or warnings when importing the file?

Answer (score 2):

To restore the dump file, and include the comments, use the [--comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_comments) option for `mysql`. For example:

```
mysql --comments -u root -p mydb<mydbbakup.sql
```

Alternatively, you can add this to your `~/.my.cnf` file:

```
echo "[mysql]" >>~/.my.cnf
echo "comments=true" >>~/.my.cnf
```